# TextArea required not working in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a small issue with a required field in a body of a bootstrap modal, ideally i want to validate the field before submitting but for some reason required is working , Can you please have a look

```
    <body>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="$dismiss()" >
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h5 class="modal-title"><b>Additional Information:</b> ( This info will be added to all incident selected )</h5>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Additional Comments :</p>
        <form name="modalForm">
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="68" id="comment" placeholder="Additional parent Info" required></textarea>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>


    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()" >Create</button>
    </div>

</body>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just for reassurance.. is this **exactly** how your HTML looks in your view?  Because if `</textarea>` is beneath `<textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="68" id="comment" placeholder="Additional parent Info" required>` then that will be considered a space..

Comment: that's not the case it's in the same line there's no space , i think that happened when i was editing to post here

Comment: What version of IE are you using?

Comment: Are you trying to validate on button click? If so, you have to include the button element inside the form tags

Comment: i tried in chrome and Firefox not working that's the main thing for me for now , am validating on button click but i want the buttons to be in the modal footer if am understanding you right .

Comment: Why can't you put the `modal footer` div inside the form tag?

Comment: am not an expert a html expert but the <form> tag is starting at modal-body <div> should i close it inside modal-footer <div> ? is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Change your submit button from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.
`required` attribute only works when there's a `submit` event listener.
Check out:
[Form inputs in modal not showing as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52526176/form-inputs-in-modal-not-showing-as-required)

Answer (score 0):

Try including the buttons inside the `form` tag:

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <p>Additional Comments :</p>
    <form name="modalForm">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" cols="68" id="comment" placeholder="Additional parent Info" required></textarea>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$dismiss()">Cancel</button>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close()" ng-disabled="inputForm.$invalid" value="Create" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: hmm I changed the button to an input.. try that

Comment: nope :( i think i might need to use some JavaScript trickery to check if the field is empty

Comment: What is `ng-click="$close()" ng-disabled="inputForm.$invalid"`?

Comment: you can remove ng-disabled="inputForm.$invalid" i was trying something else earlier , ng-click just an event listener for click on the button