# Form inputs in modal not showing as required

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-modal, required-field

I've read through some related articles without any luck of solving my own issue of getting form fields to appear as required. Perhaps the problem lies outside but I wanted to share in case it highlights a unique case.

This is a class assignment viewable in entirety [here](https://futurethang.github.io/Train-Scheduler/), it allows the user to add new trains to a schedule and update a Firebase DB. For this I used Bootstrap for the styles and also a modal pop-up that contains the form to create the new train. Everything works well, except that I cannot make the input fields required or prevent the 'submit' button.

I've tried wrapping all the fields (within their individual divs) in a  element, as well as wrapping them each in a  (as was recommended in another post) like so:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <form>
          <label for="train_name">Train Name:</label> <input class="form-control" id="train_name" required="" type="text">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form>
          <label for="origin">Origin:</label> <input class="form-control" id="origin" required="" type="text">
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form>
          <label for="destination">Destination:</label> <input class="form-control" id="destination" required="" type="text">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
</div>
</div>
```

I double-checked the Doctype for HTML5 issues, but it checks out. Is my structure just wack?

Comment: only one `form` tag would suffice, and it should be written like this: `required="required"` or just `required` to make a form element required.

Comment: Thanks, that did seem excessive. I had in earlier instances finished my input tag with the plain `required />` but it behaved the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two things.

1. The `required` attribute is only triggered when using the `submit` event listener. It looks like you are currently using `click`.
2. You are wrapping each `input` in it's own form tag. You should have a single form tag wrapping all of your inputs

Example:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <form id="my-form">
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="train_name">Train Name:</label> <input class="form-control" id="train_name" required="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="origin">Origin:</label> <input class="form-control" id="origin" required="" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="destination">Destination:</label> <input class="form-control" id="destination" required="" type="text">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>


$("#my-form").on("submit", function (e) {
  //do your form submission logic here
})
```

Comment: the OP didn't even tag [tag:JavaScript] and you're giving an answer based on it ?

Comment: Thanks . . . I clipped this out accidentally, but perhaps something is wrong with my submit button too? I placed it in the modal's footer:
`<div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" type="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
                  </div>`

Comment: @KevinHyde Ah, your right! The submit button needs to be inside the form tag as well. I updated my example 

Comment: Adding to this, please use `value=""` while using a `select` tag for required to work.

Answer (score 2):

My error with regard to the `required` attribute not working was in my handling of the Submit button. 
1. it lay outside of the `<form>` tags it belonged in, and 
2. my Javascript was also listening for `on("click" . . .` instead of `on("submit" . . .`

Making those 2 changes fixed the functionality for this concern. Thanks to [Tanner Eustice](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9325010/tanner-eustice) for the help!